# Is there an equivalent of maven's copy-dependency that copies plugins?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

For security reasons I have to work in an offline environment on a maven project. Luckily we have a local artifactory to which we can upload artifact bundles which makes it slightly less painful.

I have been using the maven-dependency plugin's copy-dependency goal (with useRepositoryLayout=true) to get new artifacts and their dependencies. I add a few dependencies to a sample project in my internet-connect machine, run copy-dependency, and I get a repo-like folder that I can send on my offline machine and then upload to artifactory.

I would like to be able to do the same but for plugins (and their dependencies). Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Usually start the build as you already did and copy the local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository` which contains the plugins which have been used during the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such plugin. But you can just delete your local Maven repository, execute the Maven build and then copy the contents of the local repository, where you can find all plugins and dependencies for your build.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. Slight improvement is running the maven command with `-Dmaven.repo.local=tmp_repo` so that you don't have to affect your usual repo for this.